# Getting "docker ps" accepts no arguments error in Python Subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, subprocess

I want to get the output of the command  `docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'` using Python Subprocess module in Flask web server

But I'm getting the following error
`"docker ps" accepts no arguments`

Works with `docker ps -a` command but fails with `docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'` command

Here is the code

```
@app.route('/get_docker_container_details', methods=['GET'])
def get_docker_container_details():

    command = "docker ps -a --format '{{json .}}'"
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = cmd.communicate()
    logger.info(output)
    logger.info(error)
    return Response()
```

Here is the log

```
INFO:automater_agent:b''
INFO:automater_agent:b'"docker ps" accepts no arguments.\nSee \'docker ps --help\'.\n\nUsage:  docker ps [OPTIONS]\n\nList containers\n'
INFO:werkzeug:172.23.100.228 - - [08/Jan/2024 12:09:51] "GET /get_docker_container_details HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The command in terminal is running ok. But I'm getting error in Flask server

So How to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `subprocess.Popen(command.split()`. Make the list yourself. The reason it receives a list is exactly to avoid this issue.

Comment: To make it clearer: You will create the list `['docker', 'ps', '-a', '--format', "'{{json", ".}}'"]` which makes `.}}'` a positional argument. And `docker ps` does not accept positional arguments.

Comment: Also consider using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/) rather than shelling out to `docker` commands; it will be a more Pythonic interface and you'll have fewer shell-quoting problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
command = ['docker', 'ps', '-a', '--format', "'{{json .}}'"]
cmd = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If we split the list, the list becomes `['docker', 'ps', '-a', '--format', "'{{json", ".}}'"]` which makes '.}}' a positional argument. And docker ps does not accept positional arguments.

Thanks @KlausD. and @zvone

Comment: Pro tip: you can use `shlex.split(command)` to split like shell. `"'{{json .}}'"` Are you sure you want the `'` quotes in output? It looks like you want `"{{json .}}"`